# GetHashCode for a type holding string fields

Tags: c#, equality, gethashcode

I have this class, where I have Object Equals overriden:

```
public class Foo
{
    public string string1 { get; set; }

    public string string2 { get; set; }

    public string string3 { get; set; }

    public override bool Equals(object other)
    {
        if (!(other is Foo)) return false;
        Foo otherFoo = (other as Foo);

        return otherFoo.string1 == string1 && otherFoo.string2 == string2 && otherFoo.string3 == string3;
    }
}
```

I get a warning "overrides object.equals but not object.gethashcode" of which I understand the need of overriding the GetHashCode, for my type to behave according to a hashable type.

As far as I researched, for this code to be unique usually the XOR operator is used, or prime number multiplications are involved. So according to my sources, [source1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/netframework-4.0/336aedhh(v=vs.100)?redirectedfrom=MSDN) and [source2](https://sodocumentation.net/csharp/topic/3429/equals-and-gethashcode) I was considering this two options for my GesHashCode override method.

1:

```
public override int GetHashCode() {
        return string1.GetHashCode() ^ string2.GetHashCode() ^ string3.GetHashCode();
}
```

2:

```
public override int GetHashCode() {
        return (string1 + string2 + string3).GetHashCode();
}
```

I am not sure either if this approaches ensures the purpose of the GetHashCode override in my case, that is to eliminate the compilation warning, and by the way ensure that the type can be handeled in collections properly, which I believe thas is that if the values they hold are equal to be considered equal, but if equal values on diferent instances take place in a collection, each needs to be found accordingly.

In the case of both of the approaches being valid, I wonder which one might be better and why.

Comment: Are you using .Net Core or .Net Framework? The answer depends on that (because there's something to help in .Net Core 3.1, but you must roll your own for .Net Framework).

Comment: `As far as I researched, for this code to be unique` The code does not need to be _unique_ (it can be _helpful_ to generate a more unique hash code - but it isn't _required_). A hash code doesn't tell you two things are equal. It just tells you whether or not they _might_ be equal (or, the inverse that they definitely _aren't_ equal). `return string1?.GetHashCode() ?? 0;` would be a perfectly valid hash code implementation.

Comment: Number two is not a correct GetHashCode probably (that depends on business requirements). It is possible to generate the same hash code for different instances of your class. Say you have one instance with string1 = "Hello", string2 = " ", string3 = "world!" and another instance with string1 = "Hel", string2 = "lo wor", string3 = "ld!". The hash code from second implementation will be the same, but instances may contain different objects thus causing your code to behave not as you expect/intend. The first one seems fine as far as I'm concerned.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/371328/why-is-it-important-to-override-gethashcode-when-equals-method-is-overridden.

Comment: @Matthew I am using the unity engine. Which I believe uses .Net Standard. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard

Comment: Ah ok, then just use the sample code in the first part of my answer. (This is in fact the code that gets generated if you use Resharper to generate a `GetHashCode()` implementation for you.)

Comment: `It is possible to generate the same hash code for different instances of your class.` That is 100% fine @LukaszNowakowski. **The same hash code does not mean two objects are equal - it just means they _might_ be equal.**

Comment: For those people claiming hash codes must be unique (i.e. no collisions) this is a simple thought experiment. `GetHashCode` can return only an `int`. I can easily write code to generate `int.MaxValue * 2 + 3` different strings. Now **by definition** at least two of those strings must have the same hash code. That is why hash codes aren't used to indicate that two objects are exactly equal - just that they _might_ be equal. The only requirement for a hash code is that two objects that are considered equal share the same hash code. https://stackoverflow.com/a/10723569/34092

Comment: @mjwills OK. I guess that for this small detail the GetHashCode mission is difficult to grasp. Thanks for your comments

Comment: All good @RustyBucketBay - your and Lukasz's misunderstanding here is a common one. Hell, you could have your hash code always return 0 if you want (if you are happy for hashset and dictionary performance to suck). It would be weird - but it would be _valid_. Perhaps consider removing your comment?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a fairly simple but effective way to do this:

```
public override int GetHashCode()
{
    unchecked // Hash code calculation can overflow.
    {
        int hash = 17;

        hash = hash * 23 + firstItem.GetHashCode();
        hash = hash * 23 + secondItem.GetHashCode();

        // ...and so on for each item.

        return hash;
    }
}
```

Where `firstItem`, `secondItem` and so on are the items which contribute to the hash code. (Larger primes can also be used instead of 17 and 23, but it really doesn't make much difference.)

However note that if you're using .Net Core 3.1, [you can do this instead](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.hashcode?view=netcore-3.1):

```
public override int GetHashCode() => HashCode.Combine(firstItem, secondItem, ...etc);
```

Incidentally, if anyone wants to look at [the implementation of `HashCode.Combine()`, it's here](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/master/src/System.Private.CoreLib/shared/System/HashCode.cs).

It's a lot more sophisticated than the code I posted. :)

Comment: Those "magic numbers" `17` and `23` are primes; using primes helps with making the hash distributed more evenly. The default setting (I think?) is that if you reach `int.MaxValue`, it automatically wraps around. If you want to explicitly state that, you can wrap this logic in `unchecked { /* logic here */ }`.

Comment: @Corak Correct, I'll add unchecked to the sample code, in case someone has enabled a `checked` build.

Comment: I'm not sure if arithmetic overflow is automatically wrapped in .NET. I'd suggest using "hash = hash ^ item.GetHashCode();" or shorthand: "hash ^= item.GetHashCode();" which won't cause exception for sure :-)

Comment: @LukaszNowakowski I *am* sure that integer calculations overflow, so I know that you definitely don't need to use `^`.

Comment: @LukaszNowakowski For completeness: The overflow behaviour is [stated here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/types#integral-types): `In an unchecked context, overflows are ignored and any high-order bits that do not fit in the destination type are discarded.`

Comment: My bad :) But I'd still go with XOR.

Comment: @LukaszNowakowski XOR is often terrible. For example, imagine a `Point` class with integer X and Y members. If you XOR X and Y together, you will get a zero for EVERY CASE where X == Y (and the same if you XOR the values' hash codes together instead). This would make it a terrible hash code.

Comment: XOR  is suggested in the documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.object.gethashcode?view=netcore-3.1

Comment: @RustyBucketBay Did you read the comment next to the sample implementation you linked? It says `The previous example returns the same hash code for (n1, n2) and (n2, n1), and so may generate more collisions than are desirable.`

Comment: @MatthewWatson, well, there're always corner cases.

Comment: @LukaszNowakowski Generating the same hash code for (X, Y) and (Y, X) for all values of X and Y is not what I'd call a corner case... Nor is generating a hash code of 0 for (X, X) for all values of X.

Comment: @LukaszNowakowski I should say though: It's perfectly fine to use XOR as *part* of the hash code calculation, as long as you shift the bits as well as XORing them - that fixes all the issues I mentioned. My criticism was only directed at the simple XORing together of all the items' hash codes.

Comment: @Matthew its not big of a deal, but as GetHasCode needs to be cheap, wouldn't it make sense to use the lowest prime numbers as possible?

Comment: @RustyBucketBay No, because the arithmetic unit on the CPU doesn't care how big the numbers are - it takes the same number of cycles whatever.